# http get timeout in javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, http, get

I have a basic piece of javascript that I am running from a .js on a windows desktop to retrieve data from https://lookup.binlist.net/ - when I run it I get a timeout on the GET line.  I have looked at various solutions and not found anything that resolves my issue.  Anyone got any ideas?

```
        var urlb = "https://lookup.binlist.net/431940";

        var xsh = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0");  
        xsh.open("GET", urlb, false);  
        xsh.send();
```

Comment: I assume the problem was resolved because the code is working when I try it.

Comment: Thanks alfredo - you have highlighted the issue that my work network is preventing the url being accessed - although I can access it through browser.  Presumably it is a security issue.

Comment: Try the same code but use a website like google.com or any website that should definitely work and see if you still get a timeout. It seems odd that you can access it via the browser and not via that javascript on that same browser.  Also, you can see what's the status returned by xsh. After the xsh.send() display the xsh.status to see if that gives you another clue to what's going on.